# How to save the selected checkbox items in Jtable to mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

In my project, I want to schedule the classes and here is my GUI.
[image: PIC]

Can someone guide me, how to save the checked value into the mysql database?

This is my save button code :

```
 private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    try{
       String sql="insert into batch (course_code,batch_number,time,"+ time_table.getColumnName(time_table.getSelectedColumn()).toLowerCase()+")values(?,?,?,?)";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        String value1=course_code.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(1,value1);

        String value2=course_code.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(2, value2+"-"+year.getText()+"-"+group_no.getText());

        String value3=time_chooser.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(3, value3);

       //String value4 = time_table.getModel().getValueAt(time_table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
     //  pst.setString(4, value4);

    int a=time_table.getSelectedRow();
    int b=time_table.getSelectedColumn();
    String c=time_table.getModel().getValueAt(a, 0).toString();


            for(int i = 1 ; i < a ; i++)
                {
               for(int j = 1 ; j < b ; j++)
                    {
                  Boolean val1 = (Boolean)time_table.getModel().getValueAt(a, b);
                  if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(val1)) {
                   pst.setString(4, c );
                        }
                    }
                }

    pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Inserted");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    }
}
```

I want something like this. [image]
This error pop ups. [image]

Comment: MySQL has a Boolean data type. So you just can insert true or false into the database :D

Comment: Yes i know. But I just know how to take the jtable checkbox values.

Comment: Do you have a database connection code or something like that? It would really help to answer your question... 
BTW.: You can insert them as Integers (0 = FALSE, 1 = TRUE), if that's what you meant.

Comment: I have edited my question. When click the checkbox I want to save the particular time on the database.

Comment: Since i answered all your questions could you pls mark it as correct answer? Thanks :D

Comment: I did it. I don't know how it undo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that is what you want (It should work as long as the columns in your database have the same name as the columns in your table):

```
    String sql="insert into batch (course_code,batch_number,time,"+ time.getColumnName(time.getSelectedColumn()).toLowerCase() +")values(?,?,?,?)";

    String value4 = time.getModel().getValueAt(time.getSelectedRow, 0);
    pst.setString(4, value4);
```

A little explanation:

```
time.getColumnName(time.getSelectedColumn()).toLowerCase()
```

should return the day you selected in lower case. It's the same as the name of your column in your database ("monday", "wednesday"). Now you are able to insert the time into the table. To do that you must get the selected row and with it you can get the cell value form the first cell of your checked row which is your time. Finally you can insert it into the database.

**EDIT:**

See comments (I can't test the code. If there are any mistakes in it, pls let me know):

```
 private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try{
            for(int i = 0 ; i < time_table.getModel().getRowCount() ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1 ; j < time_table.getModel().getColumnCount() ; j++)
                {
                    String sql="insert into batch (course_code,batch_number,time,"+ time_table.getColumnName(j).toLowerCase()+")values(?,?,?,?)";

                    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    String value1=course_code.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(1,value1);

                    String value2=course_code.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(2, value2+"-"+year.getText()+"-"+group_no.getText());

                    String value3=time_chooser.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(3, value3);

                    String c=time_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                    Boolean val1 = (Boolean)time_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
                    System.out.println(val1 + "\t");
                    if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(val1)) {
                        pst.setString(4, c );
                        pst.executeUpdate();
                        pst.close();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Inserted");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried the code. But java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.swing.JLabel error pop ups. Can you assistance why it appears?

Comment: Okay just remove the cast. I thought it would return a JLabel, but i does return a string so you can just use the string, no need for a cast. I edited my post.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It is working perfectly as I need. :) And thanks for clear explanation on the code.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Could you please tell me if I want to select multiple rows, how the code should modified?

Comment: You could loop through all CheckBoxes in the selected column and test if it's checked or not. If so then you can insert it, the same way as I did above...

Comment: Do you get an error or something? If not, put a System.out.pritln(val1 ); in your nested loop and tell me if it reads your Checkboxes correctly.
BTW.: You have to execute your statement (pst.execute();) For every val1 which is true. That means your whole method must go into your loop.

Comment: After selecting multiple checkboxs, only last checked checkbox value is saved. Sometimes this error pop up when click on save ."java.sql.SQLException: no value specified for parameter 4".

Comment: Do you want to check the whole table or just one column?

Comment: I want to select multiple rows. like if i want 8.30-1.30 time to be select on both monday and thursday , and select mutiple days with multiple times etc.

Comment: A problem is encountered with this code sir,  Boolean val1 = (Boolean)time_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j.toString());                          I change it to  Boolean val1 = (Boolean)time_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j); and run the code. But still save only one value sir.  I updated the image in the question.

Comment: I forgot to close the prepared statement (I updated the code). This should work now. If it doesn't we will make it work no worries. If there is an error again, please check some of the CheckBoxes and update the picture. Also include your console output please (I added some System.out.println).

Comment: Thank you very much sir for helping me to solve my problem. I have updated the error which occurs when it runs. Still one value is saving in the database and gives the error.

Comment: Okay, you have a database error. You declared your Batch Code as Primary Key and that's why you can't insert two values with the Batch Key. I don't know your data model, that's why it's really though to answer. If you  want your data model to fullfill all normal forms, you will have normalise your datamodel. If you don't care about that you should add a autoincrement integer field to your datamodel and set it as primary key. That will solve your error.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for helping me until the problem is fixed.. without your help I couldn't do this properly. I fixed it and now it works without any error. Thanks again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it like a String and saving it in the database in a String variable? Not pretty sure if it is possible at all. Hope can help.